# countdown from n to 0 in given time, negative end value

Tags: javascript, math, time, setinterval

I am working on simple script that should animate given value (for example `6345.23`) to `0` by counting it down, it should also end up at `0` if specified amount of time have passed (for example `2 seconds`.

I started by simple logic:

- given config: `initial value`, `time in sec`, `interval`
- time is given in seconds so convert it to milliseconds
- calculate amount of ticks by dividing time in ms by interval
- calculate amount of decreased value per tick by dividing initial value by amount of ticks

once above are known we can simply do: (simple model, not actual code)

```
intId = setInterval(function() {
    if(ticks_made === amount_of_ticks) {
        clearInterval(intId);
    } else {
        value -= amount_per_tick;
        // update view
    }
}, interval);
```

actual code:

```
var value = 212.45,
    time = 2, // in seconds
    interval = 20; // in milliseconds

var time_to_ms = time * 1000,
    amount_of_ticks = time_to_ms / interval,
    amount_per_tick = (value / amount_of_ticks).toFixed(5);

var start_time = new Date();

var ticks_made = 0;

var intId = setInterval(function() {

    if(ticks_made === amount_of_ticks) {
        console.log('start time', start_time);
        console.log('end time', new Date());
        console.log('total ticks: ', amount_of_ticks, 'decresed by tick: ', amount_per_tick);
        clearInterval(intId);
    } else {
        value = (value - amount_per_tick).toFixed(5);
        console.log('running', ticks_made, value);
    }

    ticks_made++;

}, interval);
```

Link do [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnxg83pn/) (in console you can observe how it works)

If you set time to `2 (2 seconds)` its ok, but if you set time to for example `2.55 (2.55 seconds)` it doesnt stop at all at `0`, its passing by and going indefinitely in negative values.

How i can fix it so no matter what is set in seconds its always go precisly one by one until reaches perfectly `0`?

```js
var value = 212.45,
 time = 2, // in seconds
 interval = 20; // in milliseconds

var time_to_ms = time * 1000,
 amount_of_ticks = time_to_ms / interval,
 amount_per_tick = (value / amount_of_ticks).toFixed(5);

var start_time = new Date();

var ticks_made = 0;

var intId = setInterval(function() {

 if(ticks_made === amount_of_ticks) {
  console.log('start time', start_time);
  console.log('end time', new Date());
  console.log('total ticks: ', amount_of_ticks, 'decresed by tick: ', amount_per_tick);
  clearInterval(intId);
 } else {
  value = (value - amount_per_tick).toFixed(5);
  console.log('running', ticks_made, value);
 }
 
 ticks_made++;

}, interval);
```

Comment: `amount_per_tick` is a string in this case

Comment: its actually not true, if you run the code you will see its working, if you only substract it can be string. You only have to convert to float if you are adding up, also lets focus on the issue at hand, dont lose your perspective!

Comment: The [`toFixed` method of numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) always returns a string

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky: Mevia may have been responding to my mistaken (and now removed) comment where I confused `amount_of_ticks` and `amount_per_tick`. It's true that `amount_per_tick` is a string, but as it's being used with subtraction, it'll get coerced.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, thanks :)

Comment: In your real code, you're doing something in the DOM, not just `console.log`, right?

Comment: yes ofc i am using that output for view rendering, it will be used in gaming website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[kshetline's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50247992/157247) correctly addresses why you get into negative values. When dealing with fractional IEEE-754 double-precision binary numbers (in the normal range, or even whole numbers in very high ranges), `==` and `===` can be problematic (for instance, `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` is false). Dealing with values as small as the fractional values here are, accumulated imprecision is also a factor. It's inevitable to have to fudge the final step.

But there's a larger issue: You can't rely on timers firing on a precise schedule. Many, many things can prevent their doing so — other UI rendering work, other scripts, CPU load, the tab being inactive, etc.

Instead, the fundamental technique for animation on browsers is:

- Update when you can
- Update based on where you should be in the animation *based on time*, not based on how many times you've animated
- Use `requestAnimationFrame` so your update synchronizes with the browser's refresh

Here's your code updated to do that, see comments:

```js
// Tell in-snippet console to keep all lines (rather than limiting to 50)
console.config({maxEntries: Infinity});

var value = 212.45,
  time = 2.55, // in seconds
  time_in_ms = time * 1000,
  amount_per_ms = value / time_in_ms,
  interval = 100 / 6, // in milliseconds, ~16.66ms is a better fit for browser's natural refresh than 20ms
  ticks_made = 0;
  
// A precise way to get relative milliseconds timings
var now = typeof performance !== "undefined" && performance.now
          ? performance.now.bind(performance)
          : Date.now.bind(Date);

// Remember when we started
var started = now();

// Because of the delay between the interval timer and requestAnimationFrame,
// we need to flag when we're done
var done = false;

// Use the interval to request rendering on the next frame
var intId = setInterval(function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}, interval);

// About half-way in, an artificial 200ms delay outside your control interrupts things
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("************DELAY************");
  var stop = now() + 200;
  while (now() < stop) {
    // Busy-loop, preventing anything else from happening
  }
}, time_in_ms / 2);

// Our "render" function (okay, so we just call console.log in this example, but
// in your real code you'd be doing a DOM update)
function render() {
  if (done) {
    return;
  }
  ++ticks_made;
  var elapsed = now() - started;
  if (elapsed >= time_in_ms) {
    console.log(ticks_made, "done");
    done = true;
    clearInterval(intId);
  } else {
    var current_value = value - (amount_per_ms * elapsed);
    console.log(ticks_made, current_value);
  }
}
```

```css
/* Maximize in-snippet console */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you run that, then scroll up to the `"************DELAY************"` line, you'll see that even though rendering was held up by "another process", we continue with the appropriate next value to render.

Comment: so when i will be implementing this approach - `setTimeout` part can be cut off, its just to demonstrate the point right ?

Comment: @Mevia: Yes, that's purely there to introduce a delay "outside of our control." :-)

Comment: thank you ;), that is very nice script, surely way better approach then what i had before!

Comment: @Mevia: No worries. It's something I learned from reading Paul Irish's various blog posts and such. :-)

Comment: i just have one question, sometimes it happens that `"done"` log is rendered twice, why it could be?

Comment: @Mevia: My `!done` check was in the wrong place. I moved it into `render`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're relying on `ticks_made === amount_of_ticks` being an exact match. Chances are, due to rounding, you won't get an exact match, so you'd be better off doing:

```
if(ticks_made >= amount_of_ticks) {
```

Comment: yes because i need value at the end to be exactly `0` and not `-1.39283` or `0.4485945`, math should cover this problem, i already have solution like if last tick made then hardcode value to what it should be but i dont like this kind of approach, i like when things are working correctly by itself

Comment: @Mevia: IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point (the numbers JavaScript uses) can trip you up. `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` is false, for instance.

Comment: @Mevia: You could also do `value = Math.max(value - amount_per_tick).toFixed(5), 0);` to ensure that you never go below zero. Sorry, but tricks like this are needed when dealing with the imprecision of floating point math.

Answer (score 1):

It would make sense to convert the result of `.toFixed()` to a number right away:

```
let amount_per_tick = +(value / amount_of_ticks).toFixed(5);
let value = +(value - amount_per_tick).toFixed(5);
```

*(note the `+` signs)*

Then you will never have to worry about type coercion or anything, and instead just focus on math.